# A secure and better than a normal login and check if user is login script. PHP/MYSQL code, web development

Tags: php, mysql, security, session, authentication

```
form submit { email|password }

php filter/check { mysql_real_escape_string etc... }

php set/login.php {

   $hash_logged = sha1(rand(100000,999999).$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"].time());
   $_SESSION["hl"] = $hash_logged;
   mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `hash_logged`='".$hash_logged."' WHERE 
             `email`='".$emailLogin."'")or die(mysql_error());
   setcookie("hlc", sha1($emailLogin."longstringtoguess"), time() + 600);
}
```

php script on top of all files.php to verified if a user is logged in:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["hl"], $_COOKIE["hlc"]))
{
    $ext_hl =$_SESSION["hl"];
    $ext_cookie = $_COOKIE["hlc"];
    if(empty($ext_hl))  { header("location: logout.php"); exit(); }
    if(empty($ext_cookie))  { header("location: logout.php"); exit(); }

    $mysqlQ = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `email`, `password` FROM `users`
                           WHERE `hash_logged`='".$ext_hl."'")or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($mysqlQ) == 1)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQ);
        if(sha1($row["email"]."longstringtoguess") == $ext_cookie)
        {
             $logged = "yes";
        }
        else {
            header("location: logout.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
    else { header("location: logout.php"); exit(); }
}
```

logout.php

session destroy/unset
header location: index.php

is this method secure enough?
what is your way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: use PDO mysql_ functions are no more supported

Answer (score 1):

One problem with this is users that want to connect from two devices (and hterefore two different IP addresses) or those on connections (cuch as mobile / dialup) where the IP address is likely to change. Ideally, you'd have a "sessions" table that records the hash_id and a user_id, then the user connects to a "session" and you know what user is then connected from that table.

Use of PDO is encouraged for DB entry. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php  Scary at first but makes sense and becomes second nature ("easy") very quickly.

You could also make sure your sessions "expire" if desired.

Your code is subject to someone that could steal the cookie and spoof the REMOTE_ADDR, or if someone knows the e-mail address and can crack the secret key - but for most situations this will suffice. You could add additional projection such as storing user_agent against the session (again spoofable) or adding more to the hash (rotating secret keys) and so on to make it difficult to crack.

Answer (score 1):

> is this method secure enough? what is your way to do this?

1. I don't allow SQL injection via `$emailLogin` in `set/login.php`. I prefer to use prepared statements instead, via [EasyDB](https://github.com/paragonie/easydb).
2. Instead of associating a user with a session (one-to-one), I associate the current session with a user account (many-to-one). This allows users to authenticate securely and independently from multiple devices.
3. I just use `session_start()` instead of trying to build a seemingly-secure random value. If I need to directly create randomness, I use `random_bytes()`.
4. I never use `==` for comparing strings.

   - I use `hash_equals()` instead.
   - Offending line: `if(sha1($row["email"]."longstringtoguess") == $ext_cookie)`